# Android: Record video and play mp3 simultaneously?

Tags: java, android, audio, video, android-camera

Is there a way to play a mp3 (or other) audio file while the camera is recording a video (without sound) on Android 4.x?
Has anybody ever tried to achieve this?

Comment: You can use the service to play music in background while recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to play sound while recording sound and it was working, so I'm quite sure it is possible when recording video as well. You just need to have separate threads for video recording and sound playing.

Comment: You did that with two apps or playing around with the SDK?

Comment: @kristopher but it may have delay around milisecond . How to reduce the delay ?

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.technologies.mash.MySounds.Music;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.technologies.mash.CameraPreview;
import com.technologies.mash.PlayVideo;
import com.technologies.mash.R;
import com.technologies.mash.Sound;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class AlbumDetailVideo extends Activity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private Button capture, switchCamera;
    private Context myContext;
    private RelativeLayout cameraPreview;
    AudioManager audioManager;
    private boolean cameraFront = false;
    // private ArrayList<Sound> mSounds = null;
    int z = 0;
    Sound s1;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    int sound;
    String urls;
    String audio, root, video, video_new, output;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_album_detail_video);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        // getting songpath from server 

        Intent i = getIntent();
        urls = i.getStringExtra("songpath");

//        String urls = getIntent().getExtras().getString("songpath");
        Toast.makeText(AlbumDetailVideo.this, "Sound id" + urls, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("url", urls);
        //   mSounds = new ArrayList<Sound>();

        myContext = this;
        initialize();
    }

    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    private String readTxt() {

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(z);//getting the .txt file


        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int i;
        try {
            i = inputStream.read();
            while (i != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                i = inputStream.read();
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    }

    private int findBackFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the back facing camera
        // get the number of cameras
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        // for every camera check
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!hasCamera(myContext)) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone does not have a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            finish();
        }
        if (mCamera == null) {
            // if the front facing camera does not exist
            if (findFrontFacingCamera() < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                switchCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mCamera = Camera.open(findBackFacingCamera());
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
        }
    }

    public void initialize() {
        cameraPreview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(myContext, mCamera);
        cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);

        capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(captrureListener);


        switchCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ChangeCamera);
        switchCamera.setOnClickListener(switchCameraListener);
    }

    View.OnClickListener switchCameraListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get the number of cameras
            if (!recording) {
                int camerasNumber = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
                if (camerasNumber > 1) {
                    // release the old camera instance
                    // switch camera, from the front and the back and vice versa

                    releaseCamera();
                    chooseCamera();
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone has only one camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void chooseCamera() {
        // if the camera preview is the front
        if (cameraFront) {
            int cameraId = findBackFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId >= 0) {
                // open the backFacingCamera
                // set a picture callback
                // refresh the preview

                mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                // mPicture = getPictureCallback();
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        } else {
            int cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId >= 0) {
                // open the backFacingCamera
                // set a picture callback
                // refresh the preview

                mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                // mPicture = getPictureCallback();
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // when on Pause, release camera in order to be used from other
        // applications
        releaseCamera();
    }

    private boolean hasCamera(Context context) {
        // check if the device has camera
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    boolean recording = false;
    View.OnClickListener captrureListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(AlbumDetailVideo.this, "Playing.." + urls, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            if (recording) {
                // stop recording and release camera
                mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                mPlayer.stop();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayVideo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(AlbumDetailVideo.this, "Video captured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                recording = false;
            } else {


                if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {
                    Toast.makeText(AlbumDetailVideo.this, "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
                // work on UiThread for better performance
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                        try {
                            mPlayer.setDataSource(urls);
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(AlbumDetailVideo.this, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (SecurityException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(AlbumDetailVideo.this, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(AlbumDetailVideo.this, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            mPlayer.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(AlbumDetailVideo.this, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(AlbumDetailVideo.this, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                        mPlayer.start();


                    }
                });
                recording = true;
            }
        }
    };


    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        // CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
        mCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

     //   mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC_ELD);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    /*    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(profile.fileFormat);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);*/
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        try {
            mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/rohit.mp4");
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M


        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

 /*   private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        //mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        try {
            mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M



        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }*/

    private void releaseCamera() {
        // stop and release camera
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }


}
```